# Asus F5RL - wifi cannot connect

Tags: 12.04, wireless, drivers

I am a newbie on Ubuntu. here are the details

Output of `lspci`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RC410 Host Bridge (rev 01)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RC4xx/RS4xx PCI Bridge [int gfx]
00:04.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RC4xx/RS4xx PCI Express Port 1
00:06.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RC4xx/RS4xx PCI Express Port 3
00:07.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RC4xx/RS4xx PCI Express Port 4
00:12.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB600 Non-Raid-5 SATA
00:13.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB600 USB (OHCI0)
00:13.1 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB600 USB (OHCI1)
00:13.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB600 USB (OHCI2)
00:13.3 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB600 USB (OHCI3)
00:13.4 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB600 USB (OHCI4)
00:13.5 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB600 USB Controller (EHCI)
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 SMBus Controller (rev 13)
00:14.1 IDE interface: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB600 IDE
00:14.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 Azalia (Intel HDA)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB600 PCI to LPC Bridge
00:14.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 PCI to PCI Bridge
01:05.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RC410M [Mobility Radeon Xpress 200M]
02:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4311 802.11b/g WLAN (rev 01)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros Attansic L2 Fast Ethernet (rev a0)
```

Output of `sudo lshw -c network`:

```
*-network               
       description: Network controller
       product: BCM4311 802.11b/g WLAN
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 01
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=wl latency=0
       resources: irq:16 memory:fe9fc000-fe9fffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Attansic L2 Fast Ethernet
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: a0
       serial: 00:1e:8c:d2:95:ff
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vpd bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=atl2 driverversion=2.2.3 firmware=L2 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:40 memory:feac0000-feafffff memory:feaa0000-feabffff
```

Answer (score 0):

Please do:

```
sudo apt-get purge --remove bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree
sudo modprobe b43
```

give it a few seconds and wifi should come on.