# How to connect to WiFi on Asus F5RL?

Tags: 12.04, wireless, drivers, laptop, asus

I recently installed Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS with Xfce 4.10 on my Asus F5RL AP033C laptop. When I open nm-connection-editor from the notifications area (on it the *Enable Wireless* is in grey), in the Wireless tab there are no networks, same with Wicd Network Manager. The WiFi LED on the laptop stays on all the time and I can't control it neither from Wicd nor by  pressing <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>.

Firstly, I searched the Asus site for drivers, but there were no Linux ones.

I tried adding to `/etc/rc.local` the line:

```
echo 1 | tee /sys/devices/platform/asus_laptop/wlan
```

because of these topics I've found on Ubuntu Forums:

- [wlan not working on a Asus F5R](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1224280)
- [Wifi on Asus F5r doesn't work](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1112338).

One strange thing about those is that I changed the line I was adding from `asus-laptop` to `asus_laptop`, because of the already existing folder. That `wlan` file contained `1` in it, so I edited it to become `0` and the LED turned off. I switched it back on, but I still couldn't see the list of available networks.

I've also tried:

```
sudo apt-get purge --remove bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree
sudo modprobe b43
```

as suggested in ([Asus F5RL - wifi cannot connect](https://askubuntu.com/questions/368053/please-help-asus-f5rl-wifi-cannot-connect)), but without any effect.
When I was searching the net for my laptop characteristics, I've found that my wireless is `Integrated 802.11b/g`.

`sudo iwlist scanning` returns:

```
wlan0     Interface doesn't support scanning : Network is down
lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.
eth0      Interface doesn't support scanning.
```

But there's an exception - when I first boot my laptop after being shut down it returns:

```
wlan0     No scan results
lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.
eth0      Interface doesn't support scanning.
```

`sudo lshw -C network` returns:

```
  *-network DISABLED      
       description: Wireless interface
       product: AR242x / AR542x Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express)
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 01
       serial: 00:15:af:6f:2f:ad
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath5k driverversion=3.8.0-35-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bg
       resources: irq:16 memory:fa9f0000-fa9fffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Attansic L2 Fast Ethernet
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: a0
       serial: 00:1e:8c:73:14:d3
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vpd bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=atl2 driverversion=2.2.3 duplex=full firmware=L2 ip=192.168.55.98 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:40 memory:feac0000-feafffff memory:feaa0000-feabffff
```

Except when I just start my laptop, when it returns:

```
  *-network               
       description: Wireless interface
       product: AR242x / AR542x Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express)
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 01
       serial: 00:15:af:6f:2f:ad
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath5k driverversion=3.8.0-35-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bg
       resources: irq:16 memory:fa9f0000-fa9fffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Attansic L2 Fast Ethernet
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: a0
       serial: 00:1e:8c:73:14:d3
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vpd bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=atl2 driverversion=2.2.3 duplex=full firmware=L2 ip=192.168.55.98 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:40 memory:feac0000-feafffff memory:feaa0000-feabffff
```

`lsusb` returns:

```
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:0116 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Mass Storage Device
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 174f:6a31 Syntek Web Cam - Asus A8J, F3S, F5R, VX2S, V1S
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 046d:c05b Logitech, Inc. M-U0004 810-001317 [B110 Optical USB Mouse]
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

`uname -a` returns:

```
Linux qxp-F5RL 3.8.0-35-generic #50~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Dec 4 17:28:45 UTC 2013 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

`dmesg | grep found` returns:

```
[    0.000000] found SMP MP-table at [mem 0x000ff780-0x000ff78f] mapped at [c00ff780]
[    0.120335] ACPI: No dock devices found.
[    0.148019] pnp: PnP ACPI: found 10 devices
[    1.180113] usb usb1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002
[    1.180297] hub 1-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.240054] usb usb2: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0001
[    1.240210] hub 2-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.300053] usb usb3: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0001
[    1.300198] hub 3-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.360050] usb usb4: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0001
[    1.360195] hub 4-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.420053] usb usb5: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0001
[    1.420204] hub 5-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.480054] usb usb6: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0001
[    1.480202] hub 6-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.515808] isapnp: No Plug & Play device found
[    1.518825] BIOS EDD facility v0.16 2004-Jun-25, 0 devices found
[    1.700752] usb 1-4: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, idProduct=0116
[    2.205672] usb 1-7: New USB device found, idVendor=174f, idProduct=6a31
[    2.639094] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=c05b
[   10.278986] lp: driver loaded but no devices found
[   13.667622] ath5k: phy0: Atheros AR2425 chip found (MAC: 0xe2, PHY: 0x70)
```

`dmesg | grep -i firmware` returns nothing.

`iwconfig` returns:

```
wlan0     IEEE 802.11bg  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=off   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
lo        no wireless extensions.
eth0      no wireless extensions.
```

`sudo lspci -nn` has:

```
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Qualcomm Atheros AR242x / AR542x Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) [168c:001c] (rev 01)
```

`/var/log/udev` has:

```
UDEV  [13.860291] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:04.0/0000:02:00.0/net/wlan0 (net)
ACTION=add
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:04.0/0000:02:00.0/net/wlan0
DEVTYPE=wlan
ID_BUS=pci
ID_MM_CANDIDATE=1
ID_MODEL_FROM_DATABASE=AR242x / AR542x Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express)
ID_MODEL_ID=/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:04.0/0000:02:00.0
ID_VENDOR_FROM_DATABASE=Qualcomm Atheros
ID_VENDOR_ID=0x168c
IFINDEX=3
INTERFACE=wlan0
SEQNUM=1871
SUBSYSTEM=net
UDEV_LOG=3
USEC_INITIALIZED=13860052
```

It might have something to do with the result of `sudo rfkill list all`, which changes depending on whether I unplug the ethernet cable or whether I press <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>. I explained exactly how in my comments on Olli's answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Asus F5RL Wifi problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/567131/asus-f5rl-wifi-problem)

Answer (score 0):

I had same/similar problem with my computer, and after enabling wlan from `/sys` (setting `wlan` file contents to `1`), solution appeared to be really trivial:

```
ifconfig wlan0 up
iwlist wlan0 scanning
```

Apparently `iwlist` returns `Interface doesn't support scanning : Network is down` if device is marked as down, even though device supports scanning.

Comment: `ifconfig wlan0 up` returns: `SIOCSIFFLAGS: Operation not permitted` and `sudo ifconfig wlan0 up` returns `SIOCSIFFLAGS: Operation not possible due to RF-kill`. After a bit of searching google, I've checked `sudo rfkill list all` and it returns `0: phy0: Wireless LAN Soft blocked: no Hard blocked: yes` I've found topics, showing solutions to soft blocked, i.e. `sudo rfkill unblock wifi; sudo rfkill unblock all` but mine is hard blocked and I'm out of ideas what to do next. The "hardest" solution I could think of was pressing Fn+F2 without any effect.

Comment: I just tried `sudo rm /dev/rfkill` then I rebooted and tried `sudo rfkill list all`, which returned the same result.

Comment: I repeated the same process without being connected to internet by cable. The result was the same.

Comment: I don't know why, but today when I was turning on the laptop I tried `sudo rfkill list all` and none was blocked. I did `sudo ifconfig wlan0 up` which did its thing, because it didn't return an error. Then I did `iwlist wlan0 scanning` which showed `wlan0     No scan results`. I removed the cable and everything was just like yesterday - `hard blocked: yes` and the same errors from the other two commands. Plugging back the cable did nothing.

Comment: I've confirmed that when I start the laptop nothing is blocked, but when I unplug the cable the wifi gets hard blocked. Another strange thing, I found out is that when I press Fn+F2 the result first time is `Soft blocked: yes Hard blocked: no` then I continue pressing it and check for those results `Soft blocked: no Hard blocked: yes`, `Soft blocked: yes Hard blocked: yes`, `Soft blocked: no Hard blocked: yes` and so on it changes only the soft option. After all, I can get to a state, when both are unblocked (after a reboot) and in it, `iwlist wlan0 scanning` gives `wlan0 No scan results`.

Answer (score 0):

If your Wireless is hard blocked try to enable it in BIOS

On first boot screen **enter BIOS** hit (<kbd>F2</kbd> or <kbd>F10</kbd> or <kbd>F12</kbd> - depending on your BIOS configuration)

When in BIOS **search for wireless to enable it** if disabled (Most likely under configuration -> wireless -> enabled)

When enabled **confirm and boot normally** (probably <kbd>F10</kbd>)

Hope it helps.

This command bellow in your case wont do much since you run on atheros and not broadcom driver, so not really solving any issue in your case.

```
sudo apt-get purge --remove bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree
sudo modprobe b43
```

**UPDATE**
Some Atheros drivers have issues with hardware encryption or decryption.
Try this command bellow as root user

```
echo "options ath5k nohwcrypt=1" > /etc/modprobe.d/ath5k.conf
```

Reboot, see if finally works.

Comment: I've taken a look at my BIOS and the two options I tested to enable were [Onboard LAN Boot ROM](http://imgur.com/iWHYadB) and [Wake On LAN From System Off](http://imgur.com/W5XKyuS) both of which had no effect on my problem. I didn't see anywhere else anything to do with network.

Comment: Well "enable wireless" option has to be somewhere there. Its usually located in some of configuration sub-menus under advanced or main menu depending on BIOS version. Hard block of wireless its almost always blocked in BIOS, especially if box come with Windows preloaded. Now based on your pics you checked power and  boot sections which both have  noting to do with wireless.

Comment: Checked boxes in my house but I have different versions of BIOS and  all offer configuration menu where wireless option is located

Comment: I've searched through all the tabs the first time, I just didn't show them all to you. Here they are: [Main](http://i.imgur.com/5NBpgYx.jpg), [Advanced](http://i.imgur.com/mZ0iKP4.jpg), [Security](http://i.imgur.com/mdyZQyD.jpg), [Power](http://i.imgur.com/PwDMSOc.jpg), [Boot](http://i.imgur.com/AnbTRNt.jpg), [Exit](http://i.imgur.com/GnF2nIv.jpg). Can you find the option, you're talking about from those images, or if you want me to, I'll take more?

Comment: I’m actually running off suggestions now, Could you try to check if under IDE configuration sub menu in advanced tab exists Onboard Devices Configuration or Onboard wireless menu or Onborad wlan?

Comment: Yes, I've checked [IDE Configuration](http://i.imgur.com/6PKrT5M.jpg) tab even the first time I entered my BIOS to look for the wireless enabling option. There are only the Hard Disk and CD-Rom configurations as far as I can judge.

Comment: I'm definitely out of suggestions. Atheros drivers are often not playing well with Linux in your case idk how to help you.

Comment: Actually I’m thinking that could be hardware encryption problem, based on your posted commands I'm supposing your driver is ath5k but to make it sure could you please post outcome of this command `lsmod | grep ath`

Comment: Um no need just rechecked all what you posted so far. Its ath5k please see updated answer.